Assembly loading prevents WPF application from starting after .NET 8 upgrade
After I upgraded my wpf application from .NET 4.8 to .NET 8, InitializeComponent() of the main window would throw the following exception
"The component '....MainWindow' does not have a resource identified by the URI '/...;component/mainwindow.xaml'"

Now I started resolving the issue with manually loading the URI from this question. But it's not an ideal solution to do this for more than 100 views. So I found what the real problem was.
At some place in the OnStartup of the App.cs, I load the assembly like this:
public partial class App : Application
{
  protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
  {
      base.OnStartup(e);
      var loc = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
      Assembly.LoadFile(loc);
  }
}

I also created a test WPF application and observed the same behavior -> under .NET 4.8 no issues, after a .NET 8 upgrade the mentioned exception. Does anybody know why this happens?

Your example makes little sense to me. The executing assembly is already loaded, so what is LoadFile supposed to do?

@JonasH I agree that it doesn't make much sense. A colleague wrote a method in another class, where you can pass in an assembly location and it would return you the name of that assembly by loading it. He also used that method in the OnStartup even if you could get the name of the executing assembly much easier (I assume top be consistent). I didn't put all that, cause for me it's just weird that this assembly loading messes up the URI somehow. From the linked question, I saw that other people struggle with this exception, so I found it worth mention, what could be a possible cause.

If you suspect something is an issue you could try removing that and see if that resolves the problem. That should at least help you narrow down the problem. Another thing that could help is closing VS and use "clean working directory" in your source control. That is typically needed every time I switch between revisions of a repository that uses legacy vs SDK-style projects.

@JonasH Yeah definitely, removing that assembly loading resolves the issue, you can try it out yourself. Actually the OnStartup() method had much more content, and I commented line by line until I found out the reason why it wouldn't start anymore. I just wanted to know, why a call to Assembly.LoadFile(loc) would prevent my application from starting. And why is it working under .NET 4.8 and not under .NET 8.
